# SSAS 2012 Tabular Mode

Tags: ssas, sql-server-2012

Just started to do a Tablur Mode project in SSAS 2012.  When I try to add a new Dim Table using the Existing Connection (Model > Existing Connections) it works fine and imports data and also I can see the table in Grid (Data View) Mode, but cannot see the table in Diagram View.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Added table does even show in Table > Create Relationship.  Can also create relationship.  But still doesnt come up in Diagram View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an actual relationship between the rows in the two tables, i.e. PK -> FK? Do the referenced columns have the following:
1) the same name in both tables
2) the same data type in both tables
3) data integrity between both tables

Comment: Yes Lynn there relation PK / FK between the tables with same column name and data type.  Ex:  FactInternetSales.SalesTerritoryId and DimSalesTerritory.SalesTerritoryId.  This DimSalesTerritory was added into the model lately using model existing connection.  Which doesnt establish any relation between tables though existed.  When created manually=>doesnt even show in Model Diagram View.

Comment: I tried Model>Add New Data Source to add three related tables to an existing model.  One relationship between two of the related tables was added correctly and automatically.  Also I was able to view that relationship in the designer.  I did, however, have to manually add the other relationship in the designer by dragging and dropping a connection between the related columns there.  After I did that the second relationship showed up in the designer as expected.

Comment: Thanks Lynn somehow in my first project its still not working.  Created another project it all works fine.  Only thing is it doesnt establish relationship in the Diagram View and has to create manually.